# Set value property of RadioButton

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, radio-button

I need to built a list of radio buttons, based on data I return from my DB. Each button needs to have a value associated with it that I can get out based on the selected button.

Ideally I would just use the `RadioButtonList` control, however, I need to have a very custom layout which a `RadioButtonList` doesn't appear to be able to handle.

An alternative would be to create individual `RadioButton`s and wrap them in a Panel to group them. However, there doesn't appear to be a Value property on a `RadioButton`?

Is there an alternative way to set a value to a `RadioButton` control? Alternatively, a way to completely customise the `RadioButtonList` output.

At the moment, I'm thinking I might have to resort to using HTML radio buttons with `runat="server"`, must be a better way...?

Comment: Good solution, thank you. Where are the web forms advocates now...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could create your own radio button class which extends the standard one and adds a value property:

```
public class ValueCheckBox : System.Web.UI.WebControls.RadioButton
{
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I like the solution, is there any advantage to using this over the Attributes.Add as suggested by Rahul and Marchin? Both seem to do the job.

Comment: This one would make the Value property easier to manage in the long run in case you plan to reuse the control elsewhere. I mean, just compare `radioButton.Attributes.Add("Key", "Value");` and `radioButton.Value = "value";`.

Comment: It looks like the attributes are supposed to be used for HTML attributes which get sent to the browser http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.webcontrol.attributes.aspx

Answer (score 3):

You can always try using attributes to save the associated value.
eg)

```
radioButton.Attributes.Add("Key", "Value");
```

Set the Group property to be the same for all the radio buttons and you should be good to go. Just remember, ASP .Net has a slight problem if these individual radio buttons are in different rows of a repeater, gridview or some such grid-style.

Comment: Ah yeh, forgot I could use Attributes.Add. Is there any advantage over using Travor Pilley's suggestion of extending the control? Both would work, torn between the two.

Answer (score 1):

For a quick and dirty set of STATIC radio buttons.
I used the Tag field in the Properties window to manually define a value.

If you are using a DB you should probably bind your data to it.  You never know when you'll change a key or name.

Answer (score -1):

RadioButton control doesn't have Value property, that's right. You have to use [`Checked`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.checkbox.checked.aspx) instead.

Comment: Yes but Checked just tells me whether the field has been checked or not. The buttons are dynamic so I need to store an associated value.

Comment: What do you think by 'associate value'? Do you want to do some kind of binding? That `Checked` property can be set, not only read.

Comment: I mean that if I have 3 radio buttons, each one represents a row in my database. When the user checks one, I then need to check which button has been checked and associate it with a record in my database. So really I need to store the ID along with the radio button.

Comment: You can use Attributes collection to store that kind of data or just extend RadioButton class with your own control that inherits from RadioButton.