# ASP.NET programatically adding RadioButtons to form. How to set Value?

Tags: asp.net, radio-button

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Set value property of RadioButton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9368353/set-value-property-of-radiobutton)

```
RadioButton rbtn = new RadioButton();
rbtn.GroupName = "item_selection";
rbtn.Text = Item1;
radio_buttons.Controls.Add(rbtn);
```

I am adding a series of radiobuttons programatically to a form in ASP.NET. I can add the buttons fine but I cant find how to set the "value" so that it would be the equivalent of:

```
<input name="item_selection" type="radio" value="Item1Value"/>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can do achieve this by using "Attributes" property. For example,

```
    RadioButton rbtn = new RadioButton();
    rbtn.GroupName = "item_selection";
    rbtn.Text = "Sample Text";
    rbtn.Checked = true;
    rbtn.Attributes.Add("value", "Sample Value");
    this.Controls.Add(rbtn);
```